# py-appscript & events

Tags: python, macos, itunes, sourceforge-appscript, py-appscript

Is it possible to *subscribe* to events using `py-appscript` ?

Example: I'd like to get a callback when a user changes a rating on iTunes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some very few applications are recordable: that is, they'll send Apple Events to themselves which can be intercepted. iTunes is not one of these applications.  iTunes does send distributed notifications for music start/stop, but not for rating changes.  Assuming you don't want to patch iTunes itself, your only real choice is to parse `iTunes Music Library.xml`.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  Just one small note: there is no need to parse the database.xml directly though:  I found the way to access the data through py-appscript.

Comment: Of course you can do it that way too; I just meant it'd be a file you can watch for changes.